# Wildfly 10.1 server failing to deploy/start

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly-10

When starting wildfly server with: ./standalone.sh or deploying my war I get the error:

```
21:54:04,596 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "jacks-app-1.0.war")]) - failure description: "WFLYSRV0205: There is already a deployment called jacks-app-1.0 with the same runtime name jacks-app-1.0.war"
```

As far as I can tell, nothing is deployed. Nothing in the deployments folder? Killed java and tried again, even tried a reboot.

What am I missing?

Comment: search jacks-app-1.0.war in your wildfly folders.

Comment: Searched the whole filesystem, nothing. Turned out to be inserted into the standalone.xml file under deployments tag

Comment: How are you deploying your application?

Comment: Try to delete the folders data and tmp under standalone.

Comment: Review the log.

Answer (score 2):

In the `standalone-full.xml` or `standalone-full-ha.xml` file, you can find the following:

```
<deployments>
    <deployment name="some.war" runtime-name="some.war">
        <fs-archive path="some\folders\to\some.war"/>
    </deployment>
    ...
</deployment>
```

Here you need to find and remove your `jacks-app-1.0.war` file.

Answer (score 0):

There might be another war file with same runtime name jacks-app-1.0.

Answer (score 0):

A comment is found, that should be the answer, thanks to @siom:

try to delete the folders data and tmp under standalone.